# Server cant access LDAP-Server anymore (ping possible)

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, routing, ldap

i have a vm at a customers network and that vm had access to an LDAP-Server. Since few days the access is not possible anymore. I just get the error *connection refused* or *ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)*. The VM is a ubuntu-server 18.04. According to the local admin, all other clients (windows only) can access and "nothing" has changed.

This is the Setup of the VM:

```
> sudo ip addr show
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:50:56:b1:7a:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.5.111/24 brd 10.0.5.255 scope global ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 XXX:5:250:56ff:feb1:7a6d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
   valid_lft 2591801sec preferred_lft 604601sec
inet6 XXX:5::111/64 scope global
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 YYY:56ff:feb1:7a6d/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

> cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
        addresses: [10.0.5.111/24, "XXX:5::111/64"]
        dhcp4: false
        gateway4: 10.0.5.1
        gateway6: XXX:8107:5::1
        nameservers:
            addresses: [10.0.1.11, 10.0.1.12, "XXX:1::11", "XXX:1::12"]
            search: [xyz.local, rz.xyz.local]
version: 2
```

The LDAP-Server has the ip 10.0.1.12. Regular nmap shows no open ports, as super-user i get

```
>sudo nmap  10.0.1.12

Start ing Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-09 11:11 CET
Nmap scan report for srv02.xxx.local (10.0.1.12)
Host is up (0.00071s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
53/tcp  open  domain
389/tcp open  ldap
636/tcp open  ldapssl
```

but

```
> ldapsearch -h 10.0.1.12 -p 389 -x
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

same for ldaps.
Any ideas whats causing this? Or what else i can do for diagnose?

Comment: Try *tcpdump port 389* to see traffic. To exclude problems with the ldap client, also use netcat (also known as ncat or nc) to access port 389 on 10.0.1.12. If you have access to the LDAP server, trace traffic there as well.

Comment: try running ldapsearch with the -v switch, or with -d 9 to bump the debugging info